# How to identify a damaged video file?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a simple script to get an image from a video:

```py
import cv2
z = cv2.VideoCapture("test.ts")
c,b = z.read()
cv2.imwrite("test.jpg",b)
```

Sometimes the video is corrupted and I get this image:

[image]

How to determine if an image is damaged?

Answer (score 2):

For this very special kind of image corruption, you could analyze the standard deviation along the y axis. In images like the given one, the standard deviation will be comparably lower than in real life images coming from a video stream.

The code is very simple:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def is_damaged(image):

    # Calculate standard deviation along y axis; average over all color channels
    stddev = np.mean(np.std(image, axis=0), axis=1)

    # DEBUG
    print('DEBUG:', np.mean(stddev))

    if np.mean(stddev) < 30:
        return True

    return False

is_damaged(your_image)
```

I tested the following three images, and finally the image given:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

And, these are the outputs:

```
DEBUG: 62.19297268275302
False
DEBUG: 67.96137802561054
False
DEBUG: 46.35735168890202
False
DEBUG: 21.412358349165217
True
```

As you can see, even these kind of "artificial" images have a quite high standard deviation compared to your damaged image. Set the threshold according to your data.

Again: This works (only) for this very special kind of image corruption.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Nice solution! If the image is always damaged at the bottom (only OP would know if that's the case) it might suffice to just test, say, the bottom 20%.